# The meanings of a couple of expressions

Tags: expressions

- **You sound like a broken record**
- **You're like a broken record skipping**

They mean someone repeats something over and over and it's annoying?

Are they both common?

- **She's is poor as a church mouse**

Is it still in use?

Comment: Note that you would want either *She's poor as a church mouse.* or *She is poor as a church mouse.* *She's is* is not grammatical; the *'s* stands for *is.* And I would actually prefer the sentence to be, "She is *as* poor as a church mouse."

Comment: Oops) typo! She's (as) poor as a church mouse. The first as is optional?

Comment: Yes, I think the first *as* is optional, which is why I said it's my preference. See the two example sentences in this dictionary entry: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/poor+as+a+church+mouse

Comment: **He's (as) old as me.** Can I drop it here too?

Comment: No, it is really not comparable. You need the first *as* in that sentence. (And I would actually phrase it, "He's as old as I am.") I think you can get away with dropping the first *as* with the "poor as a church mouse" simile because it is a well-known idiom. Maybe someone else can explain why the first *as* can be dropped in the mouse idiom, other than it's idiomatic.

Comment: @JLG ohh ok I see! It doesn't work in sentences such as **My car is as fast as yours.** But it does in **he's (as) red as a tomato.** Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it.

Answer (score 2):

**You sound like a broken record** is *common* among speakers who still play vinyl disks with needles; that is to say, a decreasing number of elderly people.

Of course the expression might continue to be used long after the analogy that it rests upon has lost all its meaning. Have you been hoist on your own petard lately?

As an aside, a broken record "skipping" would be likely to omit content rather than to endlessly repeat it, which rather spoils the intended effect. I have only heard (and used) the shorter version.

As for the church mouse, it is one of a group of expressions that a writer might choose to use in order to convey a particular effect describing (or harking back to) a particular time or place. For most readers, the usage would evoke earlier readings rather than first hand experience of religious rodents.

Whether or not you use any of these expressions needs to be determined (as always) by your audience and purpose.

Comment: Actually there is an ever growing number of "young people" who appreciate the analogue audio quality of vinyl to that of digital (she says as she furtively hides her 1983 JVC delux record player...) :)

Comment: But a youthful audiophile could never countenance a _broken_ record.

Comment: (*sniffs*) Perhaps not. But I still object to being called, elderly!

Comment: Rather than a "record...skipping" I believe the original expression used to be: "You ('re/sound) like a *scratched* record" or something very similar.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Does your 1983 record player play 78s. They used to get scratched a lot more easily because the heavy needles in a large 'playing head' were easily knocked and could severely scratch the record.  It would be interesting to know how far back the *scratched record* idiom goes.

Comment: Never owned 78s, but I used to play my 45s and, yes, some got scratched. Admittedly whenever I could, I'd get the CDs of my old albums too.

Comment: I have heard the broken record idiom quite a few times from perfectly normal, non-audiophilic young people—but I have to admit I’ve never heard anyone under the age of middle being hoist by their own petard.